# Unable to plot a graph, but shows up when saved to an image. Plotting multiple time series

Tags: r, plot

```
x <- zoo(score, date)
y <- zoo(score1, date1)

plot(x,ylab="Search Volume", xlab="Time",col=c(rep("blue")))
```

1. I need to plot 2 timeseries x and y.
2. And also, when I use the `plot()` function directly, a new time series does not open up, but I am able to see the output when I save the time series to a png file.

Comment: You probably have a plot window opened up elsewhere that you are not seeing.    Check your windows and try again. You can also quit R and restart it.  If that does not resolve your issue, please try to make a reproducible example as per @henrik's suggestion

Comment: Thanks! Restarting R helped!!!

Comment: Try: creating a single object and then plot that: `plot(na.approx(merge(x, y)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou everyone, somehow restarting R fixed the problem. I was trying to solve this for an hour and a simple restart works. Frustrating.